# How to localize a node.js app with different word positioning per locale mixing static & dynamic localized text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, localization, i18n-node

I have a node.js express 4 web-app I need to translate and display in several languages. I'm learning to use i18n-node package in handlebars.
Some of the localized text data comes from the db (dynamic data) and some comes from a static text json file using i18n-node. As a reference point i'll use the following sentence:
"Hey there {Londoners}! how about going to {Paris} on your next spring vacation starting on {March 29}, meet some {parisians} and learn how to cook {parisian} desserts?"
My question is: how do you deal with different grammar in various languages that will change the order of the words both static words and dynamic injected words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good localization library should support this, generally you should be able to have several things to configure/pass: key, value, variables and more (pluralization, context, etc).

The keys should be consistent across all the different language files, but the values can be whatever you want.

#### Example

Language files:

```
en.js:
  {"Hello {name}, you have {points} points": "Hello {name}, you have {points} points"}
  {"HELLO_MSG": "Hello {name}, you have {points} points"}

other-lang.js:
  {"Hello {name}, you have {points} points": "{points}, xxx, {name} yyyy yyy"}
  {"HELLO_MSG": "{points}, xxx, {name} yyyy yyy"}
```

Then, in your code you should do something like this:

```
en:
var hello1 = translate("Hello {name}, you have {points} points", {name: "John", points: 3}; // Hello John, you have 3 points
var hello2 = translate("HELLO_MSG", {name: "John", points: 3}; // Hello John, you have 3 points

other-lang:
var hello1 = translate("Hello {name}, you have {points} points", {name: "John", points: 3}; // 3, xxx, John yyyy yyy
var hello2 = translate("HELLO_MSG", {name: "John", points: 3}; // 3, xxx, John yyyy yyy
```

You can see a good example here: http://i18next.com/pages/doc_features.html#interpolation

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adir thank you for your help.
it took a while but it finally landed!

Comment: @Ajar I modified the example to include multiple variables, it's pretty similar.

Comment: I just want to add the whole Pluralization issue which was mentioned in the text but ignored in the example. English has only two plural forms (1, rest) just like in Hebrew but other languages have more forms. For example Russian has 3 forms (1,2-4,5-9 0) and it gets more complex. If your string contains something like "you have {points} points" then the word points needs pluralization.